# Posting information from an Alexa Skill to a PostgreSQL database using AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've been tasked with creating an Alexa skill that accepts commands for reading the Reddit API, return responses, and then send session information to a database. So far, I've got it where I can get a response when testing the Alexa skill and I have a payload of information I want to post to my PostgreSQL database. I'm just not sure how to make it so this payload will automatically post, though. I have a JDBC link to a PostgreSQL database. I think I would need to use API Gateway and some Lambdas, but I'm just not sure how to proceed. I'm considering switching over to DynamoDB, too, if that ends up being necessary. Here's a link to the Python file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PoF8-B9KgQuJ1-HYa5Sf_dacB_ijcLe-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Where is the code for the Alexa skill running?

Comment: @TopherIsSwell in a Lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about the architecture of your app, I can speculate on a solution.

If you run your lambda function in your own VPC (this is an option you can select from "edit function" more info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html)), then you will be able to run the Postgres db in your VPC and limit the security group to local traffic (which is arguably too permissive, but it probably good enough). You can store the database credentials (and perhaps the endpoint URI of the database) in the AWS secrets manager.

Then you can give your function a role that has permission to pull the secret from Secrets Manager (and whatever other AWS permissions it needs), and then your function, when invoked, would pull the database credentials from secrets manager (it could pull the database endpoint URI from secrets manager or it could perform a describeRdsInstances call and look for the database endpoint that way), then it would make a connection immediately, perform it's queries, close the DB connection, and send it's output back to the caller. API gateway shouldn't be needed to communicate with the database this way (though API gateway might be necessary to expose your Lambda function to be used by the Alexa service, I don't know).

If you don't want to have your lambda function run in your VPC, you'd have to find out the IP space that lambda functions (which I thought was published, but I can't find it), or open your RDS security group to all of the AWS IP space (which I would not recommend), find the totality of AWS IP space [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html), only the EC2 address space would be relevant.

However, if a port to DynamoDb is tenable, then you don't have to wrastle with the RDS Security Group, you can just give the function the correct IAM permissions to use Dynamodb, and your function will be able to reach the database. Be mindful of your request rate, because properly scaling Dynamodb read/write credits to a level that doesn't drive you broke is an art form that I have not mastered.